# How to create (with sql code) a full , differential and transaction log backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-backups

I want to generate 3 backups scripts, a full backup, a differential backup and a transaction log backup.

Assuming we are using `northwind`. How can I generate those scripts?

I would be appreciated if one can describe that step by step.

Comment: These terms really mean nothing.  You have explain what you mean by them.  A full backup of the content of the tables?  The database objects?  What exactly?  The fact that you mention scripts implies database objects -- but it is rare to do a differential backup on those so I have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how to do the full backup:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2008R2.Bak'
--optional
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2008R2';
GO
```

this is the log backup:

```
BACKUP LOG MyAdvWorks_FullRM
   TO MyAdvWorks_FullRM_log1;
GO
```

when you have a full backup you can use the backup device to perform deferential backup:

```
-- Create a full database backup first.
BACKUP DATABASE MyAdvWorks 
   TO MyAdvWorks_1 
   WITH INIT
GO
-- Time elapses.
-- Create a differential database backup, appending the backup
-- to the backup device containing the full database backup.
BACKUP DATABASE MyAdvWorks
   TO MyAdvWorks_1
   WITH DIFFERENTIAL
GO
```

it's really all there in the MSDN:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191284(v=sql.105).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191180(v=sql.105).aspx

it will also have more information about performing backups to different types of medias